# Check for flag passed to a Bash script and process value

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, flags, getopt

I have a bash script in which I want to check if a flag with value was passed to it and then use the value in a variable. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
file.sh -c 1.0.0
```

inside file.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

get flag:
if flag 'c' then 
curl c
else 
curl 'something else'
```

Whats the most optimal way to do the above?

Comment: @TharangaAbeyseela what if no argument if passed ? the script would just fail.

Comment: please check the answer. sorry i hit the enter before completion :)

Comment: [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) covers the topic in detail. Note that `getopt` is **not** a preferred solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following

```
#!/bin/bash


while getopts ":c" opt; do
 case $opt in
 c)
    echo "-c was triggered!" >&2
    ;;
 \?)
    echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
 esac
done
```